# How to Get start date and end date of a current month bootstrap datepicker dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, date, datepicker

I am trying to get current start date and end date of a month bootstrap datepicker in dd/mm/yyyy format
for example the current month in my calendar is Feb then my values will be

```
start date:1/02/2017 
and 
end date:28/02/2017
```

at the same time if I go for next month which is march then my scenario will be

```
start date:1/03/2017 
and 
end date:31/03/2017
```

I have output the value in console but what I am getting is this

```
29/1/2017
30/1/2017
31/1/2017
1/2/2017
2/2/2017

....
28/2/2017
...
11/3/2017
```

a list of date's which is shown in current datepicker

**here is my code**

```
  var active_dates = ["1/2/2017", "5/2/2017"];
        $('#datepicker').datepicker({
             inline: true,
             sideBySide: true,
             todayHighlight: true,
             format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
             beforeShowDay: function (date) {
                var d = date;
                var curr_date = d.getDate();
                var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
                var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
                var formattedDate = curr_date + "/" + curr_month + "/" + curr_year
                console.log(formattedDate);
                if ($.inArray(formattedDate, active_dates) != -1) {
                    return {
                        classes: 'activeClass'
                    };
                }
                return;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I did fixed it with datejs

This is alerting the first day:

var fd = Date.today().clearTime().moveToFirstDayOfMonth();
var firstday = fd.toString("MM/dd/yyyy");
alert(firstday);

This is for last day:

var ld = Date.today().clearTime().moveToLastDayOfMonth();
var lastday = ld.toString("MM/dd/yyyy");
alert(lastday);
```

Comment: I am trying for this https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker